# Change Navigation Drawer homeAsUpIndicator with ActionBarDrawerToggle and appcompat v7

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to change my action bar's home as up indicator. Right now it shows an arrow (when opened) and 3 stripes (when closed):

[image: navigation drawer closed]
[image: navigation drawer opened]

I want to replace this arrow with a custom drawable. The code below doesn't works:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_logo));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.string.app_name,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.app_name  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            //invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            //getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            //invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_logo));
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

If I use `<item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome|showTitle</item>` at the style, it shows my custom drawable besides the original `homeAsUpIndicator`, while what I want is to replace it

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: @MikeM. No, I'm using `<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` ...

Comment: @MikeM. ok I've changed it to `Toolbar`, but still `setNavigationIcon` has no effect. `setLogo` doesn't replace the back arrrow neither... My bet is that `ActionBarDrawerToggle` overrides it somehow

Comment: I wish I found an example that implements toolbar, navigation drawer and support.v7 together...

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?